# How can I use FindRoot on an expression from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I have a second order ODE that I can only solve numerically using NDSolve, but I then need to use the solution in FindRoot and am running into errors.  A simplified but analogous problem is the following: Find the solution to $\phi^{\prime\prime}(u) = -\omega^2 \phi(u)$ on the interval $0<u<1$ with the boundary conditions
$\phi(0)=\phi(1)=0$, which will only be true for certain values of $\omega$ ($\omega=n\pi$ in this case).  The code I am using is

```
eqnp = p''[ u] + ω^2 p[u];

psol[ω_?NumericQ] = NDSolve[{eqnp == 0, p[0] == 0, p[1] == 0}, p, u];

FindRoot[psol[ω], {ω, 3}]
```

but I am receiving errors.  How can I feed a solution from NDSolve into FindRoot?  I know that in the specific case above everything can be done analytically, but my actual ODE must be solved numerically, so I need to figure out how to solve this simplified problem completely numerically.

EDIT: I have updated the post with the full problem.  The ODE is both homogeneous and linear

```
λ = 0.00001; k = 1.0;
f[u_] := 1/(2λ u) (1-Sqrt[1-4λ+4λ u^2]);
A = Sqrt[1/2(1+Sqrt[1-4λ])];
K2[u_] := u^(-3/2)f[u](1 + 2λ u^2f'[u]);
K1[u_] := K2[u](4ω^2)/(A^2f[u]^2) - 4k^2u^(-1/2)(1 - λ(6u^2f'[u] + 4 u^3f''[u]));
eomu = 4u^3K2[u]ϕ''[u] + (6u^2K2[u] + 4u^3K2'[u])ϕ'[u] + K1[u]ϕ[u];
```

I define the boundary conditions at $u=1$ by finding the first few coefficients in the series solution (using normal Froebenius method).  I then want to find the solution and use Dirichlet boundary conditions at $u=0$ to determine the eigenfrequencies.  The first coefficient is $a1$ and the indicial exponent is $-\frac{I\omega}{2A}$ (the other solution to the indicial equation is unphysical and is discarded)

```
a1 = (k^2(1 + Sqrt[1 - 4λ])(1 + 8λ) + 2(-1 + 2λ)ω^2 + (I Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4λ]] (12λ ω))/Sqrt[2])/(2Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4λ]] (Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4λ]]/Sqrt[2] - I ω))
```

(I have separate code to find an arbitrary number of coefficients, but to enter them here would be too much) Then define the solution to use as boundary conditions

```
ϕhnum[u_] := (1 - u)^(-I ω/(2A))(1 + a1(1 - u))
numh = 0.999999;
numb = 0.000001;
```

Then I use the code suggested by Jens

```
ϕsol[ω_?NumericQ] := ϕ /. First@NDSolve[{eomu == 0, ϕ[numh] == ϕhnum[numh], ϕ'[
    numh] == ϕhnum'[numh]}, ϕ, {u, numb, numh}];

FindRoot[ϕsol[ω][numb], {ω, 1.0 - 1.0 I}]
```

When I do this I get the following error

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified     
by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the 
merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to 
meet these tolerances. >>
```

I know that for the first solution I expect something like $\omega = 1.95- 1.27 I$.  Hopefully this clarifies the problem, and thanks again for any help.

Comment: You have to give a non trivial example because this one has the trivial solution ($u=0$) when $\omega\ne\kappa\pi$.

Comment: @Spawn1701D The fact that his example has a trivial solution doesn't mean that the example is trivial. It has a non-trivial solution too (any linear homogeneous equation has a trivial solution, but nobody cares). How to obtain the latter using `NDSolve` is a valid question, which I answered.

Comment: @Jens yes you answered but you used the knowledge of the solution itself, i.e. that $p'[0]==0$. I believe the problem he wants to attack: a) doesn't know the general solution
b) his problem probably is a nonlinear or/and nonhomogeneous one.
No one questions the validity of your answer and probably with some slight modifications it can be adapted to his problem I was just curious of his proper problem.

Comment: @Spawn1701D The initial condition is $p'[0]=1$, and that's a standard choice which doesn't require knowing the solution. It's just selecting the non-trivial solution consistent with the boundary condition at $0$.   The other linearly independent solution is $p[0]=1$, $p'[0]=0$; this is always true for such equations. Basically what I'm doing is a shooting method that converts the BVP into an initial value problem. I'm sure that's what Paul is doing, and that's why `FindRoot` comes in.

Comment: In any case, OP might consider posting his actual problem instead...

Comment: @Jens I don't know what you mean by "such" equations, in general there is no consistent way you can turn a BC to an equivalent IC( without knowing the general solution of course). If by such equations you means equations that have cosines or sines as solutions then in a sense you know the general solution. In general a BC problem might not have a solution and I believe you know that the shooting method employed for solving such a problem numerically starts by a guess of the derivative at the initial point and not knowing the value of the derivative that fits the BC .

Comment: @Spawn1701D I'm just taking the question as stated: "an analogous problem is..." so we have a linear second order BVP. Then of course you can't use the initial derivative as the parameter. It's simply an eigenvalue problem, and you shoot for the value of $\omega$ that satisfies the BC. My guess is that you're reading too much into the question.

Comment: @Jens thats why I ask Paul about more info about his problem. Your answer, according to his given information, is perfectly sound.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the full problem.  Hopefully this helps to clarify things.  As mentioned in the post I still seem to have a problem.

Comment: Do not use `K` as a function name.  It is a symbol used internally by Mathematica (note that it's coloured black in the front end), and will it cause problems.  Better: don't use any names starting with capital letters, then you can avoid conflict easily.

Comment: The edit contains various syntax errors. Definitions like `f[u]` should be `f[u_]`, spaces are missing between names.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I have fixed all the syntax errors in my post.  These were errors in my posting of the solution though, in my mathematica file these problems were not there and I still have the same error message.

Answer (score 5):

There are several things that need to be corrected. First of all, to get a non-trivial solution from `NDSolve` you have to

1. specify the start and end of the interval for `u`
2. Specify two initial conditions for a second-order differential equation. Initial and final conditions (corresponding to your boundary-value problem) won't work.

Since you want Dirichlet boundary conditions, you can choose the second initial condition to be a non-vanishing derivative. With this, you'll get a solution that doesn't satisfy the Dirichlet boundary condition `p[1] == 0`.

Then the job of `FindRoot` will be to adjust $\omega$ until the latter condition *is* saitsfied:

```
eqnp = p''[u] + ω^2 p[u];

psol[ω_?NumericQ] := p /. First@NDSolve[{
      eqnp == 0,
      p[0] == 0,
      p'[0] == 1
      },
     p, {u, 0, 1}];

FindRoot[psol[ω][1], {ω, 3}]

(* ==> {ω -> 3.14159} *)
```

To make `FindRoot` work with the solution, I also had to convert the output of `NDSolve` to an actual function first. The output is a *rule*, of which I take the `First` part which then replaces the generic `p`. So in `FindRoot`, the argument `psol[ω][1]` is the solution function for a given $\omega$, evaluated at the right-hand boundary `u=1`. When that's zero, you've found the correct value of $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this problem, and for the clear explanation.  I have updated my original post with the full problem.  When I used the provided code, I still find an error, and I am not sure where it is from.  Perhaps it has to do with the boundary conditions depending on $\omega$?

Comment: I can't execute your edited new code, but the fact that you get the quoted error message means that you probably did everything right up to the point of finding $\omega$. The issue you're seeing now is unrelated to the original one. There's a lack of precision in calculating the `NDSolve` solution, or maybe the zero is not where you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was thinking that the issue is now different so it is nice to confirm that.  However I am pretty sure that the $\omega$ is near where I am searching, since I have confirmed this value in an independent way.  I will see what I can find about my current error message (which is the one given at the bottom of the original post)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more concise version of Jens's solution, using the new NDSolve-related features introduced in version 9:

```
fun = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{p''[u] + ω^2 p[u] == 0, p[0] == 0, p'[0] == 1}, 
      p[1], {u, 0, 1}, ω]

FindRoot[fun[ω], {ω, 1}]

(* ==> {ω -> 3.14159} *)
```

This will find `ω` so that `p[1] == 0`.

---

Taking the fixed equation from your last update, and applying the same method works:

```
parfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eomu == 
    0, \[Phi][numh] == \[Phi]hnum[numh], \[Phi]'[numh] == \[Phi]hnum'[
     numh]}, \[Phi], {u, numb, numh}, \[Omega]]
```

Attempting `FindRoot` gives the error you encounter and gives no correct solution.  There's a good chance that there's no solution: there's no ω so that `parfun[ω][numb] == 0`

Comment: I was working in version 8 when I wrote my answer so I couldn't go this route, but I agree this is a nice new feature (+1).

Comment: Maybe you have time to try the OP's new original code. I can't do it right now.