# FindRoot and NDSolve question with multiple parameters

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to reproduce the results from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1s67.png), which solve the equations of an elastic ring (a closed loop elastica) under various loadings. Here is the relevant part:

[image]

I need to solve the governing equations in (2), with `m0` and `p` as unknown parameters for a range of prescribed values of `f`. They indicate in the text that they solve these equations using Mathematica with `NDSolve` and `FindRoot`.

I found the following question helpful as an example: [How can I use FindRoot on an expression from NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23211/how-can-i-use-findroot-on-an-expression-from-ndsolve), and so I implemented my code in a similar manner. However, I'm trying to use `FindRoot` to solve for two parameters, and I'm not sure how to use the results of `NDSolve` to get the necessary two equations. Here is my code:

```
sol[p_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] := {\[Theta], x, y, m} /. 
  First@NDSolve[{
     x'[s] == Cos[\[Theta][s]],
     y'[s] == Sin[\[Theta][s]],
     \[Theta]'[s] == m[s] + 2 \[Pi],
     m'[s] == f/2 Cos[\[Theta][s]] - p Sin[\[Theta][s]],
     x[0] == y[0] == \[Theta][0] == 0,
     m[0] == m0
     },
    \[Theta], {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

FindRoot[{
  sol[p, m0, 200][[1]][1/2] == \[Pi], 
  sol[p, m0, 200][[2]][1/2] == 0}, {p, 0}, {m0, -10}]
```

`FindRoot` gives me an error that states:

```
FindRoot: The function value {-3.14159+0.[0.5],(-10)[0.5]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions (2) at {p,m0}={0.,-10.}.
```

It seems to me that `FindRoot` is evaluating things in the wrong order. This feels like the type of Mathematica question that is answered with "Use `?NumericQ`", [for example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037), however I am doing that here, so I'm confused. I have tried wrapping `Evaluate` around the functions in that list, but so far I've had no luck.

I suspect the issue is my lack of knowledge of how to call `sol` and use it in `FindRoot` in the presence of `?NumericQ`. For example, it works just fine, and I can visually see the roots when I plot:

```
Plot3D[{sol[p, m0, 200][[1]][1/2], 
  sol[p, m0, 200][[2]][1/2], \[Pi]}, {p, -1, 1}, {m0, -50, 50}]
```

[image: Roots for an arbitrary choice of <code>f</code>]

So clearly, the information is there, I just can't access it correctly yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1s67.png) L.N. Virgin et al., "Deformation and vibration of compressed, nested, elastic rings on rigid base", Thin-Walled Structures, 132, 167-175, (2018). [Link (Paywall)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263823118304166)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your definition of `sol` you should list all functions `{\[Theta], x, y,m}`!

Change the definition of `sol` to

```
sol[p_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] :=NDSolveValue [{
x'[s] == Cos[\[Theta][s]],y'[s] == Sin[\[Theta][s]], 
\[Theta]'[s] == m[s] + 2 \[Pi], 
m'[s] == f/2 Cos[\[Theta][s]] - p Sin[\[Theta][s]], 
x[0] == y[0] == \[Theta][0] == 0, m[0] == m0}, {\[Theta], x, y,m}, {s,0, 2 \[Pi]} ]
```

CounturPlot now shows possible solutions

```
ContourPlot[{sol[p, m0, 200][[1]][1/2] == \[Pi],sol[p, m0, 200][[2]][1/2] == 0}, {p, -1 , 1 }, {m0, -15 , -10},FrameLabel -> {p, m0}]
```

[image]

With explicitly defined equations,

```
gln[p_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ] := {sol[p, m0, 200][[1]][1/2] - \[Pi],sol[p, m0, 200][[2]][1/2] }
```

`FindRoot` is able to solve

```
FindRoot[  gln[p, m0] , {{p, 0, -1, 1}, {m0, -10, -15, -5}} ]
(*{p -> 3.80678*10^-6, m0 -> -11.9541}*)
```

**addendum**
Option `Evaluated->False` also works

```
FindRoot[  {sol[p, m0, 200][[1]][1/2] - \[Pi],sol[p, m0, 200][[2]][1/2] - 0 } , {{p, 0, -1,1}, {m0, -10, -15, -5}} , Evaluated -> False]
```

without predefinition!

Comment: Thanks. I'm also able to visualize the roots, however I'm unable to get `FindRoot` to determine them. This is important because I plan to iterate of `f`, instead of just finding the roots at `f=200`. But, `FindRoot` seems to call `Part` in a different order than `Plot` or `Plot3D`. I think this question has a similar issue, but I haven't been able to implement it correctly yet: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34355/passing-fx1-to-findroot

Comment: @dpholmes I completed my answer. With predefined equations FindRoot is able to solve.

Comment: ah-ha! the functions need to be explicitly defined before passing them to `FindRoot`. Thank you!

Comment: @dpholmes You're welcome. Predefinition seems to prevent `FindRoot` from  "SymbolicProcessing".